# How to search multiple generations in Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails

Elasticsearch's article outlines how to find objects based on a search through one generation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/grandparents.html

```
GET /company/country/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "branch",
      "query": {
        "has_child": {
          "type": "employee",
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "hobby": "hiking"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What if I want to also want to query the branch for the `name` starting with "liverpool"? How do you modify this search to find that? I keep getting format errors and I can't seem to find information about how nest the queries online.

I've already tried this (it doesn't work):

```
GET /company/country/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "branch",
      "query": {
        "has_child": {
          "type": "employee",
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "hobby": "hiking"
            }
          }
        },
        "match": {
          "name": "london"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I got an error that said the query was malformed.

I tried `bool`, but it doesn't work either; I can't use has_child with a bool.

Comment: Can you share the query you have so far and the errors you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work with a [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

If I'm understanding your question correctly, this should do what you want:

```
POST /company/country/_search
{
   "query": {
      "has_child": {
         "type": "branch",
         "query": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "has_child": {
                        "type": "employee",
                        "query": {
                           "match": {
                              "hobby": "hiking"
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "match": {
                        "name": "liverpool"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If you want the query to be an "OR" instead of an "AND", use `"should"` instead of `"must"`.

Here is some code I set up to play around with the problem:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/cf4babbbd25a3b7a26f3ea9ce9c1b686e37dbcb9

Comment: Aaah, yes. I guess I was missing the `must`